# What does unit value represent in a mutual fund?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, starting-out-investing

I've been utilizing an app that allows me to manually track all of my portfolios and see how investments are performing individually, per portfolio, and/or as an entire financial asset. I've pulled in stocks and mutual funds across Charles Schwab and Fidelity just fine but when I get to Nationwide, I noticed that instead of displaying my contribution transactions as something like

```
# of shares * net assessed value = amount contributed
```

they're instead providing

```
# of units * unit value = amount contributed
```

So for the example of the international mutual fund **RERGX**, the **NAV** is $53.41; this is what I find across different websites and it's the data the app is clearly referencing as well. But with Nationwide, the **Unit Value** is 1.9198923 and no **NAV** is provided in the transaction history.

I have no idea what this represents or how to turn it into a meaningful number to use against the app.

Comment: Is this "unit value" what is referred to as an `annuity unit (AUV)` ?

Comment: Does the Nationwide website give an explanation?

Comment: @RonJohn None that I've found in the last ~hour of looking.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I found a [court case that describes nationwide using what they call "accumulation units"](https://casetext.com/case/haddock-v-nationwide-financial-services-inc).

Comment: Need more information regarding nationwide as that doesnt tell us what type of investment this is. Is this your 401k or an annuity or life insuance?